# How do I find out what application deleted a file?

Tags: 14.04, wordpress

I use a caching plugin with my Wordpress installation. For some reason, it happens that my website's homepage get deleted from cache. No other file is deleted, just the homepage index.html file.

I have no idea what could delete the file and I do not see any mis-configuration of wordpress.

Therefore I would like to know how I can monitor the file or somehow find out what application is responsible for this. I've already looked into cron, and I don't see anything scheduled for that purpose...

Anyone can help ?

Comment: probably whatever program manages the cache. The cache should be regenerated so describe what WP cache program you are using.

Comment: I use a plugin called wp-super cache. Yes it is generated on-demand or as scheduled. But I deactivated this feature and even if it was activated it would regenerate the cache for all files. Here the index.html is simply deleted an never re-created.

Comment: wp-super created and deleted the file. If you are not using the plugin it does not matter.

Comment: what do you mean by it does not matter ?  The file is no longer on the disk, meaning it is not cached, hence bad performance on client's request (actually as soon as a client request the homepage the file gets re-created obviously, but then after a while it is deleted).

Comment: If you want to use the cache to improve performance re-activate the plug in. If the plug in is not working file a bug with the author as WP php is complex to debug and you are not using a plugin from the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: the plugin is already activated. I believe it looks like a bug indeed, but the support of wp-super cache is hopeless, they don't reply to any tickets

Comment: yes they do - https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-super-cache be patient and learn how to file a bug report - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html Do not expect much support if you post "ur plun is broken"

Answer (score 1):

Once the file is deleted, you cannot.

Comment: but maybe it could be monitored somehow ?

Comment: Deletions can be monitored with `inotify`, once you install it, read the documentation, and make use of it. After-the-fact there is no way to see where the `unlink()` call was made from.